# jQuery slideToggle on dynamically added div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some code which uses a slideToggle.

At the moment i am writing jquery for each bit of content, i.e content-one, content-two, content-three to use that slideToggle.

My problem is that i want to start adding dynamic content, so i want to change that hard coded content-xx link to just content and expand, but im not sure how to do it.

My code is as follows;

```
<div><a class="expand-one" href="#">[ - ]</a></div>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
<div class="content-one">
    // Content in here
</div>

<div><a class="expand-two" href="#">[ - ]</a></div>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
<div class="content-two">
    // Content in here
</div>

<div><a class="expand-three" href="#">[ - ]</a></div>
<div class="clearboth"></div>
<div class="content-three">
    // Content in here
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.expand-one').click(function(){
            $('.content-one').slideToggle('slow');
            return false;
        });
        $('.expand-two').click(function(){
            $('.content-two').slideToggle('slow');
            return false;
        });
        $('.expand-three').click(function(){
            $('.content-three').slideToggle('slow');
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see here i am writing little jquery blocks for each bit of content, but this doesnt work when adding dynamic content.

Is there any way that i could change the expand-xxx to just expand and content-xxx to just content so i can add as much content blocks as possible and still keep the slideToggle for each individual bit of content?

Comment: i will attach events to the body tag, therefore they apply dynamically to items under it.  For example: `$("body").on("click", ".myheader", function(){ $(this).next().slideToggle(); });` which will not require you to define a function for a new item added to the screen. It essentially says, all items under body with the class *myHeader* will execute this function, which carries out slideToggle on the next sibling div after that particular header.

Comment: @Fallenreaper that didn't work, Does it matter that there is a <div class="clearboth"></div> in between the expand and content, i will update my question

Comment: If that is between each set, then you can just say: `$(this).next().next().slideToggle();`

Comment: No, still not doing anything

Comment: That doesnt give any insight, what is the line you typed, or possible console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('.expand').click(function() {
     $(this).parent().nextAll('.content').first().slideToggle('slow');
     return false;
   });
 });
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/tr5o9mbs/18/)

Comment: Ahhh that seems to work ... Is it also possible to change the '-' to a '+' if the content is toggled or is that a completely different beast?

Comment: @CodeCodeCodeCode You can handle it by `$(this).html()`, for example `$(this).html('[ + ]')`.

Answer (score 0):

you can using php for content div, after using jquery event get data-id show content
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btlDp.jpg)

Comment: Im afraid it needs to be javascript only